# Overriding agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer in Ag Grid

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a ag grid data table and I'm updating those values. I'm trying to use the **agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer** and its working completely fine but I cant override the style and timeout of it. Its the default ag grid animation style.

```
 const columnDefs = [
  // these are the row groups, so they are all hidden (they are showd in the group column)
  {
    field: 'product',
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true,
    rowGroupIndex: 0,
    hide: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'portfolio',
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true,
    rowGroupIndex: 1,
    hide: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'book',
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true,
    rowGroupIndex: 2,
    hide: true,
  },

  // all the other columns (visible and not grouped)
  {
    field: 'batch',
    width: 100,
    cellClass: 'number',
    aggFunc: 'max',
    enableValue: true,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    field: 'current',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    field: 'previous',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Change',
    valueGetter: changeValueGetter,
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'PL 1',
    field: 'pl1',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'PL 2',
    field: 'pl2',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Gain-DX',
    field: 'gainDx',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'SX / PX',
    field: 'sxPx',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: '99 Out',
    field: '_99Out',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Submitter ID',
    field: 'submitterID',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Submitted Deal ID',
    field: 'submitterDealID',
    width: 200,
    aggFunc: 'sum',
    enableValue: true,
    cellClass: 'number',
    valueFormatter: numberCellFormatter,
    cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
  },

  // some string values, that do not get aggregated
  { field: 'dealType', enableRowGroup: true, enablePivot: true },
  {
    headerName: 'Bid',
    field: 'bidFlag',
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true,
    width: 100,
  },
  { field: 'comment', editable: true },
];
```

Does anyone knows how to override the timeout of agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer?

When I click update the style shows but the timeout is quite fast.
Please check the sample app [AnimateShowChange](https://plnkr.co/edit/DfYu70bWEWQnm6ky?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&preview)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can override the animation timeout and delay by adding these two into your default grid options see GridOptions

```
  cellFlashDelay: X milliseconds,
  cellFadeDelay: X milliseconds
```

Depending on how you're overriding your AG Grid styles, you can update the cell flashing colors by changing this in your css

```
.ag-row .ag-cell-data-changed {
   border: 1px solid red !important;
   background: transparent !important;
}
```

If you've got arrows indication increase/decrease of numbers, you use these two to override their colors

```
.ag-value-change-delta-up {
   color: lime !important;
 }

.ag-value-change-delta-down {
   color: $railpen-orange !important;
}
```

Hope this helps